# Multiple steps of branching probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, problem-solving

There are $4$ urns.

urn A has $2$ black balls and $6$ white balls

urn B has $4$ black balls and $4$ white balls

urn C has $6$ black balls and $2$ white balls

urn D has $8$ black balls

You choose an urn at random with equal probability, then draw $3$ balls from it, one at a time, without returning any back to the urn. What's the probability of drawing a black ball if $2$ black balls were drawn in the first two drawings?

I understand that I have to multiply probabilities in order to find one "branch" and then sum all the branches, but I keep getting wrong answers like $\frac{1}{2}  \text{or}  \frac{5}{14}$ and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Have you used Bayes' Theorem?  Have you heard of Bayes' Theorem?  Are you correctly conditioning on the fact that the first two balls drawn are black?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952508/probability-urns

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142363/probability-of-drawing-balls-from-two-urns-bayes

Comment: I did not use Bayes' Theorem, I figured I could just multiply the probability of having reached urn A by the probability of the next ball in that urn being black, do the same for all the other urns and sum the result

Comment: @VadimChernetsov neither of those match the current scenario and emphasize the color of the first ball(s) drawn and how they influence our belief about the rest of the draws.  @ Tsidia, this is a problem testing your knowledge and understanding of how and when to use Bayes' Theorem.  Look at Bayes' Theorem.  Understand it.  Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem Setup:

Let events $A,B,C,D$ be the events that we happened to be drawing from urns $A,B,C,D$ respectively.

Let $X$ be the event that the first two balls drawn happened to be black.

Let $Y$ be the event that the third ball drawn happens to be black.

You are tasked with finding $\Pr(Y\mid X)$.  To do this, recognize that $\Pr(Y\mid X) = \Pr((Y\cap A)\cup (Y\cap B)\cup (Y\cap C)\cup (Y\cap D)\mid X)$

$ = \Pr(Y\cap A\mid X)+\Pr(Y\cap B\mid X)+\Pr(Y\cap C\mid X)+\Pr(Y\cap D\mid X)$

$ = \Pr(Y\mid A\cap X)\Pr(A\mid X) + \dots +\Pr(Y\mid D\cap X)\Pr(D\mid X)$

The value of pieces like $\Pr(Y\mid C\cap X)$ can be found intuitively.  This for instance, we are asking what the probability the third ball drawn will be black given we are pulling from urn C and two black balls have already been pulled.  Well, in this scenario, there are $4$ black balls left after our earlier pulls out of $6$ balls in total giving $\Pr(Y\mid C\cap X) = \dfrac{4}{6}$

The rest of the pieces such as $\Pr(C\mid X)$ can be found from Bayes' Theorem.  Recall that $\Pr(C\mid X) = \dfrac{\Pr(X\mid C)\Pr(C)}{\Pr(X)}$.  Each of the pieces here should be readily obtainable.  I leave the rest of the calculations and piecing of everything together to you.

Comment: Mr. Moravitz, can you solve this problem through binoms?

Comment: $\dfrac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}$ is the same as $\dfrac{6\cdot 5}{8\cdot 7}$.  If you insist on using binomial coefficients where applicable, then you can certainly use binomial coefficients.  Nothing I have written here prevents that.  That being said, I expect it to be unnecessary.

Comment: Mr. Moravitz, so what is the answer to this problem? I want to check with the mine result.